# Intuition for what it means to be an invariant vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, intuition

I am trying to understand [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1725873/340973) about left invariant vector field. I don't understand in the example with the river flow. What is exactly $F$ and $f$ in this example?

> Now if the two games coincide then you have that the vector field is
> invariant i.e. $X_{F(p)}(f)=X_p(f∘F)$
>
> You can think about this with an hypersimple physical example:
> Consider a river and a thermometer. The river is flowing so a particle
> of water is moved along the flow. If you're interested on the changing
> of temperature along the flow of the river, in any given time you can
> either measure the temperature few istants after the time given
> measuring the temperature in the new place where the particles will be
> or you can measure now the temperature of the particles and assign
> this temperature to the place where you guess they will be given the
> velocity they have.

Comment: The English is clumsy. But I would say $F$ is the velocity of the river (as a function of position and time) and $f$ is the temperature (as a function of position).

Comment: Isn't the vector field $X$ the velocity?

Comment: Yes, I was not careful. $F$ is the flow. I'm used to putting a time parameter in there. And, of course, $X$ is the velocity field. My apologies.